# Trying to take specific data from a file and make a tuple out of the specific data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an assignment and am trying to figure out how to take certain data from a file (that is ordered by 'Title', 'year', 'Genre', 'Director', 'Cast') and make it into a tuple so I can use it as a key to a value - dictionary style. I want to take the 'Title' and 'year' and make them a tuple like so: ('Title', 'year') then make the values as 'Cast' (the number of casts for each title varies). This is what I've come up with but I can not figure out how to take from the file and put into a tuple. Any help will be awesome, thank you!

```
def list_maker(in_file):
    d = {}
    for line in in_file:
        l = line.split(",")
        for i in l:
            if i == l[0]:
                x = i
                print(i)
            elif i == l[1]:
                y = i
            title_year = tuple(x, y)
        print(title_year)  # checking to see if it does what I want
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PyCharmWorkspace/HW5/Problem 2(a).py", line 44, in <module>
    list_maker(in_file)
  File "C:/PyCharmWorkspace/HW5/Problem 2(a).py", line 20, in list_maker
    title_year = tuple(x, y)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you add your input and expected output?

Comment: Depending on the value of `i`, either `x` or `y` (or none of them) gets defined, but never both.

Comment: also this is a site for learning and getting help from people in the community.  do you really want your name to be @Buttscratcher ?

Comment: Do you know what bravosierra even means? Its used at time to call "bullshit." Do you want to be a hypocrite or not? Don't pick at names. I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments before, you are attempting to use a variable that you may or may not have assigned.  Your first iteration through the for loop you assign a value to *x*, but have not assigned a value to *y*, but you try to use it in *tuple*

```
  for i in l:   <--first iteration
       if i == l[0]:  <--- True
            x = i    <--- x is assigned the value of i
            print(i)
        elif i == l[1]:  <---- False
            y = i     <--- DOES NOT HAPPEN
        title_year = tuple(x, y)   <--- python doesn't know what y is
```

That being said you don't need that for loop at all, you can just do your assignments linearly.

```
def list_maker(in_file):
    d = {}
    for line in in_file:
        l = line.split(",")
        x = l[0]
        y = l[1]
        title_year = (x, y) #this is all you need to generate a tuple
        print(title_year)  # checking to see if it does what I want
```

Comment: Why `tuple(x, y)` and not `(x, y)`? Or just: `title_year = (l[0], l[1])`

Comment: I usually try and change as little code as possible to explain what the poster is having issues with.  But in this case I think you are right, updating...